# Cannot change property of GTK button

Tags: python, pygtk, glade

I have a code that changes the sensitivity of a `gtk.Button` to `False` once the action `clicked` is fired.
After a background process finishes I want to change it back to `True` but for some reason it doesn't work.

The function I call to change it is the bellow `show_dialog`. Printing the button object gives me that:

```
<Gtk.Button object at 0x7ff41b1bed38 (GtkButton at 0x1f0cf80)>
```

Trying to set the label and the sensitivity as shown do not work. What intrigues me is that the success dialog executed after that works perfectly.
All widgets come from a `.glade` file.

Is there anything I'm missing here?

```
def show_dialog(self):
    button = self.builder.get_object('button')
    print(button)
    button.set_label('Changed')
    button.set_sensitive(True)
    success_dialog = self.builder.get_object('parse_success_dialog')
    success_dialog.set_transient_for(self.window)
    response = success_dialog.run()
    if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
        success_dialog.destroy()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifications in the widgets of the main window cannot be done outside the main thread.
The method of the question was being executed in a Handler class, that way it could not modify the button from the main window.
The solution for this problem was the creation of a `idle-add` call that calls a function in the main window and modifies the button.

So in the Handler I have (note that the function comes from the window):

```
GLib.idle_add(self.window.show_dialog)
```

And in the window class I put all the function `show_dialog`.